# Use a for loop to get the difftime from the row above

Tags: r

I found a [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/4dn2td/filter_objects_with_a_specific_distance_by_date/) and it got me thinking of how to get the difference from the row above using a for loop. I tried the approach below, but wasn't quite nailing. Is there a better method to approach getting the difference from the row above, dates or numbers?

```
test <- data.frame(Dates=rbind("2006-08-07 19:33:02","2006-08-07 19:34:02","2006-10-10 19:33:02","2006-10-11 19:34:02" ,"2006-10-12 19:34:02","2006-10-13 19:34:02","2006-10-14 19:34:02"))


for (i in 2:nrow(Dates)){
  difftime(i[2-1,],i)
}
```

Comment: To make a column vector, you can use `c` instead of `rbind`.

Comment: Why to use a for loop? Your title is misleading. You should just describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to convert your dates to an actual date format

```
test <- data.frame(Dates=rbind("2006-08-07 19:33:02","2006-08-07 19:34:02","2006-10-10 19:33:02","2006-10-11 19:34:02" ,"2006-10-12 19:34:02","2006-10-13 19:34:02","2006-10-14 19:34:02"))

df <- test %>% mutate( Dates = as.POSIXct(Dates),
                       Diff = Dates - lag(Dates) )
df
                Dates       Diff
1 2006-08-07 19:33:02    NA mins
2 2006-08-07 19:34:02     1 mins
3 2006-10-10 19:33:02 92159 mins
4 2006-10-11 19:34:02  1441 mins
5 2006-10-12 19:34:02  1440 mins
6 2006-10-13 19:34:02  1440 mins
7 2006-10-14 19:34:02  1440 mins
```

Answer (score 1):

Since many R functions are vectorised, you don't need a loop at all, in this case.

Try this:

```
test <- data.frame(Dates=rbind("2006-08-07 19:33:02","2006-08-07 19:34:02","2006-10-10 19:33:02","2006-10-11 19:34:02" ,"2006-10-12 19:34:02","2006-10-13 19:34:02","2006-10-14 19:34:02"))

test$Dates <- as.POSIXct(test$Dates)

diff(test$Dates)
```

The result:

```
Time differences in mins
[1]     1 92159  1441  1440  1440  1440
```

Comment: That makes sense, how would the `diff()` change if there weren't a specific function for this example? Say I wanted to multiply the row above to the current row?